# Search API's and Display Data Without Saving to Database First - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have worked on a project for a few weeks now and have run into problems displaying the data I get from various api's. I want to use <%= render @search.products %> so that I can paginate the results but I keep getting the following error.

```
ArgumentError in Searches#show

Showing /app/views/searches/show.html.erb where line #10 raised:

'{:total_count=>69, :incomplete_results=>false, :items=>[{.... json data here .....}]}' is   not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.
Extracted source (around line #10):

10:     <%= render  @search.products %>
```

Model search.rb

```
def candidates  
  @search ||= find_product.items
end 

def store
.... Store Client ....
end 

private

  def find_products
    products = store.search_products('location:"#{location}"', order: "desc") if location.present?
    products = store.search_products("#{size} ", order: "desc") if size.present?
    products = store.search_products("#{brand}", order: "desc") if brand.present?
    products
  end
```

Controller searches_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json {render json: @search.candidates }
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this:

```
<%= render @search.products %>
```

If you have a partial **app/views/products/_product.html.erb**, try this:

```
<%= render partial: 'products/product', collection: @search.products %>
```

There is a nice [blogpost](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/renderable-null-objects) that explains where your error come from if you want more informations.